# Is com.google.common.collect.Ordering.arbitrary reliable in a 64-bit address space?

Tags: java, comparable

`com.google.common.collect.arbitrary()` claims to produce a reliable comparison of arbitrary objects via `System.identityHashCode(Object)`.  However, since the hashCode is a 32-bit quantity, I don't see how this could work in a 64-bit address space, where there may be more than 2**32 object instances.  Is my skepticism justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code reveals that in case of a collision between two identity hash codes of different objects, the comparator falls back to a map associating each of the objects with a counter that is incremented each time a new object is stored in the map.

See http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#line.200